# Jqgrid auto complete extender not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, autocomplete

I am using the below code to create an auto complete extender in edit and add form. Edit form doesn't show while i use the $(e).autocomplete({ });. Please help me to solve this..

```
{ name: 'FLD_IP_ADDR', index: 'FLD_IP_ADDR', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "text", formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 3, elmprefix: "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='required'></span>&nbsp;" },
                            editoptions: {
                                dataInit: function (e) {
                                    $(e).autocomplete({
                                        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            editrules: {
                                edithidden: true,
                                required: false
                            },
                            edittype: "text",
                            hidden: true

                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

i just added this and it is now working for me

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-front {
        z-index: 1000;
    }

</style>
```

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jquery-ui-1-10-2-autocomplete-drop-down-renders-behind-jqgird-form